# Error in cqlsh command line while querying

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh, cassandra-cli

I have a three node `Cassandra` cluster running perfectly fine. When i do `select count(*) from usertracking;` query on one of the node of my cluster.  I get the following error :

```
  errors={}, last_host=localhost
  Statement trace did not complete within 10 seconds
```

Although, it's working fine on rest of the two nodes of the cluster. Can anyone tell me the why i am getting this error only on one node and also what is the reason of error?

As given in this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766976/cassandra-cqlsh-query-fails-with-no-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766976/cassandra-cqlsh-query-fails-with-no-error/%22Post%22) I have also increased the time out parameters `read_request_timeout_in_ms and range_request_timeout_in_ms` in cassandra.yaml. But that didn't help.

**KeySpace definition :**

```
CREATE KEYSPACE cw WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 3 };
```

**Table definition :**

```
CREATE TABLE usertracking (
  cwc text,
  cur_visit_id text,
  cur_visit_datetime timestamp,
  cur_visit_last_ts bigint,
  prev_visit_datetime timestamp,
  prev_visit_last_ts bigint,
  tot_page_view bigint,
  tot_time_spent bigint,
  tot_visit_count bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (cwc)
);
```

Output of **node tool status** :

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.200  146.06 MB  1       ?       92c5bd4a-8f2b-4d7b-b420-6261a1bb8648  rack1
UN  192.168.1.201  138.53 MB  1       ?       817d331b-4cc0-4770-be6d-7896fc00e82f  rack1
UN  192.168.1.202  155.04 MB  1       ?       351731fb-c3ad-45e0-b2c8-bc1f3b1bf25d  rack1
```

Output of **nodetool tpstats** :

```
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
ReadStage                         0         0             25         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0         257103         0                 0
MutationStage                     0         0         593226         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0              0         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0         612335         0                 0
CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0              0         0                 0
ValidationExecutor                0         0              0         0                 0
CommitLogArchiver                 0         0              0         0                 0
MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
MemtableFlushWriter               0         0             87         0                 0
MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0             87         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              3         0                 0
MemtablePostFlush                 0         0           2829         0                 0
CompactionExecutor                0         0            216         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
HintedHandoff                     0         0              2         0                 0

Message type           Dropped
RANGE_SLICE                  0
READ_REPAIR                  0
PAGED_RANGE                  0
BINARY                       0
READ                         0
MUTATION                     0
_TRACE                       0
REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
COUNTER_MUTATION             0
```

Comment: This is a symptom and fixing it by increasing the timeout will probably not solve the overall problem. Can you share `nodetool status` and `nodetool tpstats` output (the latter should be executed during the query runnning). Also having a look at the table definition might help us.

Comment: @Lyuben I have updated the question. Kindly look at it if it helps

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this helps. I have a very similar configuration in my development environment and was getting OperationTimedOut errors when running count operations.

Like yourself, I originally tried working with the various TIMEOUT variables in cassandra.yaml, but these appeared to make no difference.

In the end, the timeout that was being exceeded was actually the cqlsh client itself. When i updated/created the ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc file with the following, I was able to run the count without failure.

```
[connection]
client_timeout = 20
```

This example sets the client time out to 20 seconds. 
There is some information in the following article about the cqlshrc file: [CQL Configuration File](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html)

Hopefully this helps, sorry if I'm barking up the wrong tree.